# Regex not meeting the requirement

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am trying to learn `Regex` construction, and i am stuck in one problem.

Problem Statement:
A regex that should match following phrases:

```
rap them
tapeth
apth
wrap/try
sap tray
87ap9th
apothecary
```

but should not match

```
aleht
happy them
tarpth
Apt
peth
tarreth
ddapdg
apples
shape the
```

My attempt:

```
^[a-z0-9]+p.?t
```

My regex is matching `tarpth` as well. How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you clarify the logic of those sets?

Comment: With your stated requirement: `^(?:rap them|tapeth|apth|wrap/try|sap tray|87ap9th|apothecary)$`

Comment: @DenysSéguret This is sample problem i picked from http://regex.sketchengine.co.uk/cgi/ex2.cgi

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Certainly this is the solution to the problem, but it looks like piping the keywords themselves should not be done. Reason for it is, it won't be having much logic embedded in it. But thanks for suggesting this way as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a puzzle, not a real question

Comment: @GauravGupta: Why it should match `apth` but not `tarpth` ?

Comment: @anubhava bcoz problem statement demands this?

Comment: @GauravGupta I was just pointing out that your problem statement is unclear, if you don't state the logic explicitly a bruteforce approach will do fine.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I got your point, Even brute force is a way to get solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/mV9qD7/1) does the trick, it's a very specific question thought:

```
(ap)(.?)t
```

Answer (score 2):

This meets this requirement:

```
^([a-z0-9]+p.{1}|[a-su-z0-9]+p)t
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/yY3lV6/1

Answer (score 2):

This should do it - you failed to require `a` before the `p`:

```
.*ap.?t.*
```